# Jquery accordion drag and drop to a drop area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I am trying to implement a feature with **jquery** accordion much like the **MS Outlook** accordion feature where, when I minimize the accordion,there is an area at the bottom where the accordions are put and when I maximize the height of the accordion the elements are taken back to accordion container.

Well,I don't know how to do that and if anyone has any idea,please help me .This the first question.

So as an alternate solutions I thought of doing that like drag and drop. I want to put a div at the bottom of the accordion where I can drop the current accordion elements. The thing I want to implement and have done some parts are:

1. I've made accordion elements sortable so that I can drag and drop to that div
2. I've made a div where I want to put/drop the accordion elements,hence made that dropapble
3. When I drop from accordion container to bottom container, it should remove that from accordion and put the dropped object into that bottom div but show as icon to users.
4. By bottom container is also sortable/draggable and I can put back the accordion element from bottom to top accordion elements.
5. When I drop from bottom to top, bottom will remove that element and top will append that.

I have already started to implement and here is the code in **JSFIDDLE** [Custom accordion D&N](http://jsfiddle.net/8SUbN/7/).

The problem I am facing is

- when I drop the jquery ui.element object how to store that in that div and show as icon.
- And the points 3-5 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're going for but this might be a little closer:

http://jsfiddle.net/8SUbN/12/

```
$(function() {

   $( "#accordion" ).accordion().sortable({
       connectWith: "#dropBag"
   }); 

   $( "#dropBag" ).sortable({
       connectWith: "#accordion"
   }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example provided only the accordion header is being dragged,
this will end up in strange behaviour if you click to open the pannels,
therefor it is better to enclose each section in its own div.

```
<div class="demo">
<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
            odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>
            Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
            purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
            velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
            suscipit faucibus urna.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>
            Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
            Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
            ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
            lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>
            Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
            et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
            faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
            mauris vel est.
            </p>
            <p>
            Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
            inceptos himenaeos.
            </p>
            <div id="dropBag" class="ui-widget-header" style="height:50px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

And then to activate the sortable function of the accordion change the header to "> div >h3"

```
$(function() {

   $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ header: "> div > h3"}).sortable({
      connectWith: "#dropBag"
   }); 

   $( "#dropBag" ).sortable({
       connectWith: "#accordion"
   }); 

});​
```